# Creating a custom sorting function for use as an option in script

Tags: javascript, sorting, listjs

I'm using the vanilla JS script [list.js](http://www.listjs.com/) and am trying to implement a custom sorting function.

I have been using the `sort` method from the [List API](http://www.listjs.com/docs/list-api) without issues for normal sorting, however need to create a *custom sort* for a couple of situations, however because he never provided an example I'm unsure how to do it.

For example I have this code:

```
var options = {
    valueNames: [ 'date', 'amount', 'company', 'name' ]
};

// Instantiate our list
var myList = new List('mylist', options);

// Set our default sort
myList.sort('date', {order: "desc"});

// Control our own sorting via the links

$('a.sort').on('click', function(event) {

    // Prevent default action
    event.preventDefault();

    var element = $(event.target);

    // Get sorting method
    var method = element.attr('data-sort');

    // Work out what way we want to order the results

    switch (method) {
        case 'date':
        case 'amount':
            var order = 'desc';
            break;
        case 'company':
        case 'name':
            var order = 'asc';
            break;
        default:
            var order = 'desc';
    }

    // Sort the data
    myList.sort(method, {order: order, sortFunction: function(a, b, options){

    }});

    return false; // IE 8

});
```

He never stated the expected signature for the function, but I worked out it has 3 parameters filled with data, the first two seem to contain elements from within the sorting list and the third has options of some kind.

I have read about using [custom sorting functions](http://freewebdesigntutorials.com/javaScriptTutorials/jsArrayObject/customSortFunction.htm) but unsure how to complement them here.

One example of a sort we would need is that we have a list of dates, such as:

- 2015 Spring/Summer
- 2014 Spring/Summer
- 2013 Winter
- 2005 Fall

It should sort by highest number first (in this case 2015) then  season in this order first to last: winter, fall, spring/summer.

Is it possible to make a custom sort for stuff like that and if so how can it be implemented with this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sorting function should return a negative number if `a` should come before `b`, 0 if it shouldn't be changed, or a positive number if `b` should come before `a`. Here is one possible implementation, assuming the date is a predictable string with the format `YYYY {{season}}`.

```
// Putting the season in the keys for ease of use and assigning them values so we know which one comes first.
var seasonMap = {
    'Spring/Summer': 0,
    Winter: 1,
    Fall: 2
};

var order = 'asc'; // ascending or descending

function sortFunction(a, b) {
    var coefficient = order === 'asc' ? 1 : -1; // If the order you pass it is 'asc', the a positive coefficient will retain this function's ascending sorting order; otherwise it will invert this function.

    // Convert the dates into arrays by splitting them by a space ' '
    var aDateComponents = a._values.date.split(' '),
        bDateComponents = b._values.date.split(' ');

    // The 0th value of the array is the year; additionally convert it into a Number instead of a String
    var aYear = Number(aDateComponents[0]),
        bYear = Number(bDateComponents[0]);

    // The 1st value of the array is the season; look up the value from the map object we created in the beginning so we know which season comes after which
    var aSeasonNumber = seasonMap[aDateComponents[1]],
        bSeasonNumber = seasonMap[bDateComponents[1]];

    if (aYear !== bYear) {
        // return aYear - bYear. If a > b this will put a after b. The coefficient will invert it if we're sorting descending.
        return coefficient * (aYear - bYear);
    }

    if (aSeasonNumber !== bSeasonNumber) {
        // Same thing here. Since the season was mapped to a number, we know which season comes first and can return a positive or negative difference.
        return coefficient * (aSeasonNumber - bSeasonNumber);
    }

    // Don't change the order otherwise.
    return 0;
}
```

You should also validate the date string first, and check if it's a valid season.

Comment: Interesting - thanks. So I can just give that function a name and then pass that in as the `sortFunction` parameter value?

Comment: Indeed, or just put that anonymous function in as a parameter.

Comment: Just tried it out; got *a.date is undefined*; I'm not 100% sure but I think `a._values.date` may be the way to reference it?

Comment: Sure. Do whatever works; the List API isn't that clear.

Comment: Agreed. FWIW it seemed to work, so you may want to update your answer. :)

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm not sure whether `_values` is private API so you might want to be careful.

Comment: Hmmmm true. I just had a look through the object after logging it to the console and that seemed to be the place to find them.

Comment: I made a similar function for sorting another field that contained numbers with strings such as: `55,000,000 Some Text` and followed the way you did this function but it doesn't work for some reason - no errors, just doesn't change the sort of the list at all. If it's not of bother, can I show you it in chat?